# UITableView Transparent

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit

I just want to know how i can set a transparent background of an UITableView.
I got this :

```
tableview.backgroundcolor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But the cells stay white and not transparent.

Thank for help

Flo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That statement is correct for setting the tableView's background color to clear (transparent), not the cells.

You have to manipulate cells directly, as they themselves are views. When you set the background color of a table cell however, you are not setting the background color of its content view. So unless you do that specifically, you won't see through the cell. Try this to make transparent the cell background and the cell's contentView background:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

(Written from memory here, not compiled... :-)

Comment: Thanks that exactly what i was searching for.

Comment: Realize that this will impose a performance penalty if you're scrolling a table view with a large number of cells. Try to avoid transparency when possible.